# Update mongodb collection with a object via eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I would like to save the following object to a field on a mongodb collection via eloquent

```
 "project_settings" : {
    "resource" : true,
    "zone" : true,
    "contractor" : true,
    "responsible_person" : false
 }
```

this is my php code:

```
return ProjectModel::where($project_id)->first()->update($project_data);
```

dont worry about the model it works fine i need to make a query that updates the project collection

and $project_data =

```
project_settings:array(4)
  resource:true
  zone:true 
  contractor:true
  responsible_person:true
```

Right now i get no error back. It returns successful but nothing is updated in reality. Can someone help?

Comment: What is `$project_id`? `where` should have something like array there `where(['id' => $project_id])` for example. How it is written now, I suspect that it is not known what column is meant for `$project_id`. Also, you can remove `->first()` part. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates).

Comment: did you use any package for connection mongo and eloquent

Comment: Dont worry about the project_id. it is just the id of the project to update

Comment: yes i use eloquent and mongodb package it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably with your inputs.

The method signature of `update` looks like below:

```
public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
```

So the attributes you pass in must be an array, not an object.

The `where()` method also need two inputs like `where('column_name', $value)`.

So try something like below:

```php
ProjectModel::find($project_id)->update([
    "project_settings" => [
        "resource" => true,
        "zone" => true,
        "contractor" => true,
        "responsible_person" => false
    ],
]);
```

Comment: that is exactly how i am declaring my inputs

Comment: my inputs are arrays. and my project_id variable is an array that looks like this 
_id:"5ff44e3da4170000ae007375"     so the _id works fine that is not the problem i think.

Comment: Okej it works now when i removed the "first" method